# array value pass to command appendRow (google-actionscript)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script:

```
function Hojas3()
{
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var hojas = libro.getSheets();
  var hoja0 = libro.getSheets()[0];
  var  matriztexto = [] ;

  for ( var s = 0 ; s < hojas.length ; s++)
  {
    matriztexto += "["+(hojas[s].getName()+", "+hojas[s].getSheetId()+"], ");
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(matriztexto);
  hoja0.appendRow(matriztexto);

}
```

Like everybody can see the alert show me a array but the appendRow Command  interprets like string what is my wrong..?

Here is the error obtained :

```
appendRow(string). (línea 47, archivo "Código")
```

line 47 refers to `hoja0.appendRow(matriztexto);`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. If things were that obvious ... why are you asking a question here? So please read [mcve] and consider improving your question.

Comment: This script has a error: " appendRow(string). (línea 47, archivo "Código")" my line 47 is "hoja0.appendRow(matriztexto);"

Comment: Don't put more information into comments. Update your question instead please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Hojas3()
{
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojas = libro.getSheets();
  var hoja0 = libro.getSheets()[0];
  for ( var s = 0 ; s < hojas.length ; s++)
  {
    hoja0.appendRow([hojas[s].getName(),hojas[s].getSheetId()]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works but wrong way..
appendRow show  messages of this type : [Ljava.lang.Object;@5d264438

Comment: Works fine..
may be we can conclude that appendRow only accept an array of type 1xN..?

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).

Comment: thanks a lot Cooper, myself understand the reference on different way because for me, an array is not limited for 1 file x n column Way I will try be most simple when I gonna read the reference